# How to create appropriate html markup for email

Tags: html, css

I am not an expert in html, but I need to create a normal markup for the email message that the program sends to the email. I assume that the recipients mostly use Outlook.

I'm trying to send a validation error message saying there is a mismatch in the number of items in an order. I need to list items in an order created in one information system versus items entered in another system. I have a markup and I want to have the same padding between SKU and quantity for different items so that they align like in the table. But I don't want to use a table to create markup. I end up using the 'pre' tag, but the markup in the email is sprawling. I want the email to look like this

[image: Correct appearance of part of the email]

But instead I get the following

[image: Wrong appearance of part of the email]

Here is part of the html code I use to create this part of the email.
Much appreciated for any help with markup

```
<pre style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&#9 6-14/01 &#9 quantity: 20</pre>
<pre style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&#9 6-14/01 &#9 quantity: 14</pre>
<pre style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&#9 17-902/01 &#9 quantity: 24</pre>
<pre style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&#9 589-00/01 &#9 quantity: 16</pre>
<pre style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">&#9 589-00/01 &#9 quantity: 16</pre>
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use a table? That data looks like exactly the kind of thing tables were designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `<pre>...</pre>` tag, which basically means "make this stuff look like it's displayed on an old-school DEC vt100 terminal". Then you're using tab characters '&#9` to space out your tables. And, on a vt100 there was a tab stop every 8 spaces.

Try using a simple html table. That should do what you want in any mail reader.

Comment: I am sorry for my 'backend' approach -;) I tried to build the body of the letter in the simplest way.  You are probably right and I should use a 'table'